# Need help finding revenue function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, economics

I'm hoping someone can help me start off on the right foot for this project in my college algebra course. I am to find $R(x)$, the weekly revenue as a function of units sold. I can identify the revenue as a price but having a hard time determining how to express it as a function of **UNITS**. Here is the demand equation that I have calculated from the given stats.

$$y = -.0109x + 5.4287$$

The points from the stat table that I would like to use are $(x = 355, p = 1.5)$

This gives me the function of $$R(x) = xp = (355 -1.5p)p = -1.5p^2 + 355p$$

From here I can determine the cost functions & profit functions, but I cannot determine how many loaves are to be sold in order to maximize revenue.

Comment: What is y in this context?

Comment: y = -.0109 + 5.4287 is the slope that I obtain from a table of units sold vs price given over weekly sales. With a negative correlation of -.996

Since originally posting this, I have figured out that the revenue function would be

R(x) = -.0109x^2 + 5.4287x

I am now stuck at finding the domain of the cost function at 400 units

1.182 = cost to produce units
50.85 = cost to pay back a loan used to purchase equipment weekly.

C(400) = 1.182(400) + 50.85